# How Can I execute my code on MessageBox Ok click

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, messagebox

This might be very simple but I am new to MFC.

I have a messagebox:

```
MessageBox("Do You Want to Save the Configuration Changes","NDS",1);
```

which have Ok and Cancel option. I want to write my code on click of OK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(MessageBox("Blah", "NDS", 1) == IDOK)
{
   // they hit okay
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I ve never used IDOK, just IDYES to execute anything! ;)

Comment: @Sunscreen, according to the MSDN documentation in the link I provided, `IDYES` is defined as 6 and `IDOK` as 1.  Therefore, trying to check against IDYES from a MessageBox called with flags of `MB_OKCANCEL` will not work as it will never be returned.

Comment: The flag i use is MB_YESNO and therefore i always get IDYES if the user presses the Yes. Anyway, it was a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the return value is `IDOK`, and execute your code if it is.